# Check if javascript source is using prohibited functions

Tags: javascript, parsing

I want to run user provided javascript on site, but before doing so, I need to (algorithmically) check if provided javascript source follows set of rules (e.g.not using eval() function, not using setTimeout()/setInterval() functions, etc.).

Nice thing in addition would be to check if source is valid.
Tool for this could be anything, since executed server-side.
Do you have any ideas what may be useful for this ?

edit: code will be executed in web worker environment

Comment: @AndrewHubbs, There is absolutely nothing wrong with this question.

Comment: myspace tried to do this a long time ago. i bet they spent tons of money on expert programmers doing it. they kept getting hacked. you shouldnt try.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible to tell if a script is going to use a prohibited function by simply scanning through the source code.  You have the change the environment the script executes in.

What you're doing is not a simple text search.  JavaScript is a very dynamic language, and you could effectively call a "prohibited" function without having the name of that function in the source code at all!

```
window['e'+'v'+'a'+'l']
```

It also isn't possible to simply execute the script and track which functions are accessed, as you won't be able to hit all code paths.

To prohibit usage of specific functions, you must run the code in a sandbox where those functions do not exist.

Comment: "The only thing you can do to prevent usage of specific functions to fire up a JavaScript sandbox where those functions don't exist." You say that like it's not a perfectly cromulent solution to the OP's problem.  That's exactly what he should do (imo).

Comment: @Malvolio, What do you mean?  That's exactly what I'm proposing he do!  And yes, that's the only solution to the problem.  I completely agree.

Comment: Perhaps I just misread your tone.  You start two sentences with "the only".  One simply won't work; the other is a good idea.

Comment: @Malvolio, Thanks for the feedback.  I have edited to be more clear.

Comment: Yes, that code is valid argument. However: Isn't there possibility to eliminate variable access ? I can determine, when variable is accessed (from some parse tree ? similar to calling function) - so accessing window[] means insecure (-> not accepting code). If there is small, finite way to do this, isn't it possible to just check for  those 'special' variables.

Comment: (meant as small amount of special variables, that may provide security weakness).
_Second_: Environment to run user provided javascript is worker, therefore `window` and many other is not accessible. This may solve part of issue, still need to detect (regular) function calls. (It doesn't matter if function call is not reachable, there shall not be anywhere in source)

Comment: If you blacklist functions, people will always find a way around it, or you will strip the environment down so much that common scripts won't be able to function.

Comment: Actually, the 'freedom' I need to provide is not that big. Provided source code need access to Math object, able to call defined functions, standard control (if,while,...) and integer/string/array operations, so I may be able to whitelist features. Not sure if that helps ...

Comment: @3p1i4, That's precisely why you should whitelist instead, building a JavaScript sandbox with only what you need available.  You mention though that you need to detect usage, and not prevent it.  If that is the case, I do not have a suggestion for you.

Comment: Yes, I missed your edit previously.  Whitelisting what is available in your sandbox is exactly what you should do.

Comment: Might want to mention using "strict mode" to prevent the suspicious code from getting access to the global context.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running it server side (on Node.js or Rhino or something like that), *you* have control of the global namespace.  Take `eval` and `setTimeout` out of it.

Comment: Provided source code is running in client browser (in worker environment)

Answer (score 0):

If the JavaScript is running in a web browser, execute it on a page loaded from a separate domain ("exampleusercontent.com") in an iframe. Then use [window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) to allow communication with the parent window (from "example.com"). This is more or less the way Facebook Apps work.

The untrusted JavaScript will, unfortunately, be able to do things such as redirecting the user to another Web site or hanging the user's browser; however, it should not be able to inject code into "example.com" or steal the user's "example.com" cookies.

For actually prohibiting certain functions in the way you are thinking of, [Google Caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) is an open-source compiler for sandboxing third-party JavaScript, although from time to time, someone has discovered a vulnerability in it.